# Does groundwater flow depend on the geometry of the aquifer?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow, porous-media

[image: Top: aquifer geometry; bottom: hydraulic head]

I consider two cases of a confined aquifer and want to calculate the pressure / hydraulic head in a quasi 1d case. These two cases are shown in my drawing.
I assume homogenious, isotropic darcy flow, and use the [groundwater flow equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Groundwater_flow_equation), without time dependency (steady state flow) and no sources or sinks. So the equation simplifies to a simple Laplace equation
$$ 0 = \alpha \nabla^2 h $$,
where $h$ is the hydraulic head. In one dimension this can be written as
$$ 0 = \alpha \frac{\partial^2 h}{\partial x^2} $$.
If the boundary conditions are known, $h_1$ at the left boundary, $h_2$ at the right boundary, $h_2 > h_1$, I conclude, that $h$ probably looks like I have drawn it in bottom left, because if the second derivative of $h$ is zero, then the first derivative has to be a straight line, and therefor $h$ needs to be a parabola.

So my first question is, given that I have not made a mistake until here, how do I know if the parabola has positive or negative curvature? (line or dashed line in the drawing).

And the second question: What does change in the case, that I have drawn on the right? Is the hydraulic head the same? Is the pressure different?

Comment: Write $\binom{50}{k}\binom{50}{k+1}=\binom{50}{50-k}\binom{50}{k+1}$ then use

Answer (score 0):

If the formation height is constant and you use the 1D form of the equation, then x must be measured along the channel and h is a linear function of x.  In particular, $$v=-K\frac{dh}{dx}$$ where v is the superficial velocity (constant) in the x direction and K is the hydraulic conductivity.  If $h_2>h_1$, the flow is in the negative x direction.  In the second figure, v will be lower in magnitude because the path is longer.

Comment: So my application of the Laplace equation in this case is not correct then?How do you know that $v$ is constant?

Comment: The flow in the right hand figure is really 2D (velocity components in the x and z directions), so you have to take that into account.  One way of doing this is to use the distance along the middle of the channel as the coordinate.  This reduces it back to a 1D problem.  I called it x in my equation, but it should really be given a different symbol (say, s) to distinguish it from the horizontal coordinate x.  The velocity v along the channel is constant because the channel height is constant and the flow is steady state, so conservation of mass dictates that v be constant.

Answer (score 0):

to answer this question

the right figure has variable aquifer bottom, unlike the left one which has constant aquifer bottom

from groundwater model prospective on real case, it has been proven that the variation in the aquifer bottom dose affects the groundwater flow in some way.In fact this is the actual case for most groundwater flow systems that you don't have uniform aquifer bottom
hence different aquifer geometry

for more detail on this problem chick Never Krisk Book title: Hydrogeology and Groundwater Modeling 2007

Comment: This  doesn't provide a *well-justified* answer. You  should state some governing principles for your statement of "it has been proven." You haven't provided any details, and a link to a book without giving some pertinent summary isn't a good answer, either.

Comment: Proven by mean I did a research on groundwater movement using a proven equation to investigate variable aquifer bottom and we get non-uniform aquifer profile I can't give you a whole detail of a research that I'm not the only author, which mean I need permission from my other colleagues . I refer to the text book where there is an equation that has the derive of the 1D analytical solution with variable aquifer bottom. All you have to do just go find the text I refer and try different scenario on the equation... it is that simple

Answer (score 0):

you can't have constant velocity unless you have a uniform hydraulic conductivity (k). In other words, constant velocity that means homogeneous-isotropic aquifer